# Is it possible to write to the same temp table using SELECT INTO?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write to a temp table , the source data can come from two different sources but they do have the same schema.  the source of data is selected by a conditional statement IF ELSE   only one can execute,  but sql doesn't seem to like that . it complains the table already exists.  here is the piece of code. "Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_xxx, Line 37 [Batch Start Line 0]
There is already an object named '#my_temp_table' in the database. "

```
IF @flag = 0 
    
    SELECT * INTO #my_temp_table 
    FROM source_A
    
ELSE             
    BEGIN
        --even tho the temp table will not exist i am trying to by pass the error 
        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#my_temp_table ') IS NOT NULL
            DROP TABLE #my_temp_table 

        SELECT * INTO #my_temp_table 
        FROM source_B
    END
```

Comment: This is a parsing error. You cannot try to create the same object twice within the same batch (even if logic would dictate that both statements cannot be run). If the definitions of the 2 objects (`source_A` and `source_B`) is the same, the `CREATE` the temporary table first with the correct definition and then `INSERT INTO` it. IF not, then use different object names, as having an object with the same name but different definitions is only going to cause your trouble down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on here that are or will be issues for you.

SQL Server's `SELECT...INTO` logic is how Microsoft chose to implement the more standard `CREATE TABLE AS...` syntax (which is then followed by a `SELECT` statement in most dialects). You can only create that table once, and then it's there.

Local temp tables (with a single `#`) continue to exist until your session disconnects from the instance. So if you try to run the above code twice without disconnecting, it'll fail.

You're using `SELECT *`, which is going to bite you when somebody changes the schema of one source table.

All that said, you don't need all that logic. You can do what you want with one query.

```
SELECT
  <Column List>
INTO #my_temp_table 
FROM 
  source_A
WHERE @flag = 0
UNION
SELECT
  <Column List>
FROM 
  source_B
WHERE @flag <> 0;
```

Comment: The " * "  above was just to simplify the query . The union approach with where condition, solves my problem! .  The strange thing is with my t-sql ,  it is guaranteed that the temp table won't exist before SELECT INTO because of the IF ELSE statement . It looks like the parser is just detecting  multiple SELECT INTO the same table  and deciding it is not allowed , event tho there is no way both cases will execute .